# Referencing / Parsing an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very simple question here, I have the following variable. set up in a format like so {item number: quantity, item number, quantity....}

```
var x = {4214061251:1,2497227651:2,4214140739:2};
```

My question is simply how do i loop through this properly to access each element.

I would like to be able to access the item numbers and quantities separately, how can I achieve this?

Comment: for(var key in x){console.log(key, x[key]); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var x = {4214061251:1,2497227651:2,4214140739:2};

// Array of all keys 4214061251, 2497227651 ...
var keysArr = Object.keys(x);
console.log(keysArr);

// Iterate on keys
keysArr.forEach(
  (el) => {
    // To access keys
    console.log("Key: "+el);
    
    // To access values instead
    console.log("Value: "+x[el]);
  }
)
```

Comment: why such a complicated logic, you can directly use **for(var key in x){console.log(key, x[key]); }**

Comment: @RahulSharma If you use for in to loop over property names in an object, the results are not ordered. Worse: You might get unexpected results; it includes members inherited from the prototype chain and the name of methods.

Comment: the results are not ordered? I didn't understand this because in JSON object you can't decide the order or keys. please help me to understand.

Comment: `If you use for in to loop over property names in an object, the results are not ordered` They're not ordered when using `Object.keys` either. Admittedly they *usually* are, but there's absolutely no guarantees. Ordering is irrelevant to the OPs question, anyway.

Comment: @RahulSharma This might be interesting for you then https://stackoverflow.com/a/23202095/1496715

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yea I agree.. I was quoting something why for ... in are not considered a solid approach to iterate over objects, until unless coupled with `.hasOwnProperty()`

Comment: this did work for what i was looking for, if there is a simpler way just let me know!